# How to connect to a VPN to get data from an API in python?

Tags: python-3.x, vpn, binance

I have data that I need to get through an API (binance international) but I do not have access to it as I am in the US.

I found some packages for nordvpn and expressvpn, but nothing which allows you to execute via command line from OSX.

I am trying to figure out if there are VPN clients which will allow me to connect in some ways like so:

```
import a_vpn_service
import binance

a_vpn_service.connect(country=ireland)

client = binance.Client(api_key=API_KEY, api_secret=API_SECRET)

transactions = client.get_account_trades()

for trade in transactions:
    print(trade)
```

I don't know if there are any VPN services that exist like this, or where I could find one. If anyone has any help or advice, that would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a python VPN client. you can install a VPN software Like ExpressVPN or NordVPN, etc. then connect and run your python script.

Comment: This is for a server running on an amazon lightsail server, though @beh.f. and there are other aspects (coinbase US) that need to be queried from the US, or I believe there are problems that arise.